# Why is this embedded iframe video not playing?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video, youtube

I want to add this video on my website. I added this code but it’s not working. Please help me.

```
<div id="container">
  <iframe id="vid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhxVR2Szu3k&noredirect=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<style>
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 560px;
    text-align: center;
}
#vid {
    margin-bottom: 25px;   
}
</style>
```

Comment: video not displaying

Comment: please check the code

Comment: it's worth mentioning that `frameborder` is a deprecated attribute [check it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#deprecated_attributes).
You can use `border: none` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED**
Please replace this with your code

```
<div id="container">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NhxVR2Szu3k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and css

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

as you are not using correct code for video..go in video link..then share and then embed code and take that code and it will work..hope this help.

Updated : now your video is responsive..change width according to your need.

Comment: I need one more help this video is working but when video is completed its continue for next video but i dont want next video

Comment: that's the huge issue of youtube..you can clear individual cookies and then run youtube again but m not sure it will help as a lot user facing this issue..read more here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/ZSdaqRSmG2k

Comment: yes...please check my updated code..change width according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly understand what you're trying to achieve but try this example:

```html
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>  
            <div style="text-align:center"> 
              <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause </button> 
              <br> 
              <video id="video" width="420">
                <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
              </video>
            </div> 
            
            <script> 
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("video "); 
            
            function playPause() { 
                if (myVideo.paused) 
                    myVideo.play(); 
                else 
                    myVideo.pause(); 
            } 
            </script>               
</body>
</html>
```